# Passing list as a parameter for a INSERT statement executed through psycopg2 (2.8.5)

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

```
data = [2, 5.5, 'Harry Potter']

statement = "INSERT INTO ranks (Rank, Height, Name) values(%s, %s, %s)"

#made a connection to a postgres database using psycopg2
```

I want to pass the list named `data` as a parameter to the `cursor.execute()` function used to execute the statement.

> Note : As the the `data` list contains elements with different data
> types, I cannot use the string.join() method on it.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

Basically:

```
cur.execute(statement, data)
```

So pass a sequence of values to the query that will match the `%s` parameters in order.

**UPDATE**. Doing:

```
create table ranks (rank integer, height numeric, name varchar);

import psycopg2
con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test host=localhost user=aklaver")
data = [2, 5.5, 'Harry Potter']
statement = "INSERT INTO ranks (Rank, Height, Name) values(%s, %s, %s)"
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(statement, data)
con.commit()

select * from ranks ;
 rank | height |     name     
------+--------+--------------
    2 |    5.5 | Harry Potter
```

works. So your error must be with some other data or statement.

Comment: When I am trying to implement this, it is throwing an error. 
"ValueError: unsupported format character  ',' "

Comment: See **UPDATE**. Also complete traceback or complete data and code used that got the error would help.